# How do I get the image to change when the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im sorry to be such a noob but when it comes to programming i have a lot of difficulty so if someone could help that would be great!

Basically I am trying to make a zindex with a few images in which I'd like when I click the button it switches the image. I know this is probably very basic but I am very lost on what to do. I understand the concept but cannot input it.

I am also trying to get the images to be in the middle of the page. I was recommended to the following; however, that did not work. Can someone please help?

Here is what I have:

**CSS**

```css
#xbone {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index:-1
}
#ps4 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index:-2
}
#wiiu {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index:-3
}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
function changeStackOrder() {
    document.getElementById("xbone").style.zIndex="1";
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<img id="xbone" alt="Xbox One" width="800" height="600"
     src="http://assets1.ignimgs.com/vid/thumbnails/user/2013/06/19/XboxOne1.jpg">
<img id="ps4" alt="Playstation 4" width="800" height="600"
     src="http://www.nowgamer.com/siteimage/scale/0/0/360062.jpg" >
<img id="wiiu" alt="Wii U" width="800" height="600"
     src="http://venturebeat.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/wii-u.jpg" >
<input type="button" onclick="changeStackOrder()" value="Change stack order">
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GkGJw/

Comment: I would suggest you include a jsfiddle post with your code sample in future as a best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function changeStackOrder() {
    $("img").each(function() {
        $(this).css("zIndex", "+=1");
        if($(this).css("zIndex") == "0"){
            $(this).css("zIndex", "-3");
        }
    });
}
```

Try something like this

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Is "this" in the function being replaced with the ID? Also where does the "img" go in the html? sorry.

Comment: I have changed my codes a little bit. "this" means the element you are selecting, in this case, it is each of the "img" tag. "img" is your img tags, you have them there already

Comment: sorry but im confused. so i keep the "img" you put in your code and replace this with each of my picture tags? and what do you mean you changed your codes a little bit? sorry. and thank you again.

Comment: as my codes are jQuery, you need to include jQuery in your page, and keep everything you got in your html section and put my codes in the script section. My code means for each "img" element, aka your image, add up 1 to the z-index, whichever reaches 0, it becomes -3 .

Comment: I put your code in and the page is not changing. this is what i have:<script>
function changeStackOrder() {
    $("img").each(function() {
        $(xbone).css("zIndex", "+=1");
        if($(ps4).css("zIndex") == "0"){
            $(wiiu).css("zIndex", "-3");
        }
    });
}
</script>

Comment: Thank you so much dude. Works great. I have to get your contact info. your a great help :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not changing because setting the zIndex of xbone to one still makes it on top. If you would do it for any of the other images it would appear on top.